# How can I make my Single Page Application (SPA) based on React render conditionally?

Tags: css, reactjs, animation

I am making a personal website based on ReactJS. Since this is a Single Page Application, I want to make my website be rendered conditionally. That is the **Render** should render each **section** on my page at different time when users **scroll down** to view different **section** on my page, because I want my components to be **animated** when users view this , instead of all of these components being animated in the beginning.

```
        <Section styles='me' id={'top'}>
        <img className="background-image" src={require('../img/Sydney.jpg')} />
        <Animated animationIn="zoomIn" animationOut="zoomOut" isVisible={true}>
        <div><Avatar src={require('../img/me.jpg')} size={200} round={true} /></div>
        </Animated>
        <h1>Jack Lau</h1>
        <h3>Web/Mobile Apps Developer</h3>
        <h3 style={{ maxWidth: 480 }}>Core Skills:<br/>Ready for React, Redux, Typescript, ES6, JSX, Babel and Webpack. Objective-C, Android Development, C#, JavaScript, PHP, Database Design</h3>
        <div style={{ marginBottom: '30px' }}>
            <a href='https://www.linkedin.com/in/jacklau9515/' className='btn-icon' target='_blank'><i className='fa fa-linkedin-square'></i></a>
            <a href='https://github.com/Jacklau9515' className='btn-icon' target='_blank'><i className='fa fa-github-square'></i></a>
            <a href='https://plus.google.com/u/0/100888601415107489035' className='btn-icon' target='_blank'><i className='fa fa-google-plus-square'></i></a>
        </div>
        <Animated animationIn="rubberBand" animationOut="zoomOut" isVisible={true}>
        <a href='#hire-me' className='btn'>Hire Me!</a>
        </Animated>
        </Section>

        <Section styles='resume'>
        <div id={'background'}>
        <img className="background-image" src={require('../img/xpic11075_sc115.com.jpg')} />
        <h3 className='title'>My Personal Introduction</h3>
        <Animated animationIn="fadeInLeft" animationOut="rollOut" animationInDelay="3" isVisible={true}>
        <p>I graduated from <a href="http://www.utas.edu.au/" target="_blank"><u>University of Tasmania (UTAS)</u></a> in December 2017 with an undergraduate degree (Bachelor of Information and Communication Technology, Software Development). Participate in the implementation of <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dbdc/id1296090690?mt=8" target="_blank"><u>Digitized Bike Data</u></a> Project and served as Leader Software Developer of the team.</p>
        <p>I am very detail oriented. You can easily contact me at any hour of the day, and I am enthusiastic and passionate about architectural and design patterns, best practices and cutting-edge technologies.</p>
        <p>During my three years of university study, no less than a Distinction (DN) Grade of All my programming-related subjects, especially web programming. The following table shows the scores and descriptions of all my programming subjects:</p>
       </Animated></Section>
```

Note: the **Animated** is a React component to show or hide elements with animations using Animated.css.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is meant for people to ask for help, and the etiquette is that you have a go yourself, and people will help you complete the task. You can read more about it here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach you could take:

When you are building your Component, establish some form of internal State - Keep track of the Scroll Position of the Browser and update this with some sort of event handler. When this position reaches the point at which you would like your component to Animate, flip a boolean within the internal state.

In the Render Method, you can use `{{Expression/Variable/Const Evaluating to True} && <Component>}` to render the component conditionally, only if some certain state is met.

Here is some example code. I am not sure how performant this would be in terms of React/Re-Renders, and I can't say that this code will necessarily work - I'm just trying to point you into the right direction; some logics you may try to apply.

The principle of rendering conditionally through JSX is a powerful one that you can use to selectively render components based on some custom logic scheme you develop..

```
class AnimatedContainer extends Component {
    Constructor(props) {
     super(props)

     this.state = {
      renderComponent1: false
      scrollPosition: "0"
     }

     this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this)
    }

    handleScroll(scrollPosition) {
     this.setState({
      scrollPosition = document.documentElement.scrollTop })
       if (scrollPosition > 300) { this.setState({ renderComponent1: true })}
    }

    componentDidMount() {
     window.onscroll = () => this.handleScroll(this.state.scrollPosition)
    }
    componentDidUpdate() {
     window.onscroll = () => this.handleScroll(this.state.scrollPosition)
    }

    render() { 
     return(
       <div>
        {renderComponent1 && <AnimatedComponent1>}
       </div>
     )}
}
```

I have been informed that a better method would be to use addEventListener:

```
windowScroll = () => this.handleScroll(this.state.scrollPosition)

componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.windowScroll)
}
componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.windowScroll)
}
```

Edit: You will also have to implement your animation logic separately - I'm assuming your Animated Components will have their own methods for doing this.